# Why can't I deselect some packages in Buildroot, marked with -*-?

Tags: buildroot

When I navigate through the Buildroot setup with `make menuconfig` (I'm using version 2021.11.x) I see some options that are marked `-*-` and cannot be deselected.

For example, under `Target Packages` -> `Networking applications`, `cups` is marked `-*-` but I would like to deselect it.

I tried editing the `.config` manually (probably not advisable?). Even after commenting out `BR2_PACKAGE_CUPS=y` it still shows `cups` marked `-*-` in `menuconfig`

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: That means that the option is a required dependency of some other option that you have selected.  I think that if you press 'H' with the cursor on the option, it will tell you what that other option is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment to my question

> That means that the option is a required dependency of some other option that you have selected. I think that if you press 'H' with the cursor on the option, it will tell you what that other option is.

`H` shows all the info you need about a package and showed me which package depends on `cups`. In my case, since I manually selected `openjdk`, `cups` was autoselected (and could not be deselected) because `openjdk` depends on `cups`.